# Is it Possible to Output an Empty Value Using yq?

Tags: json, null, yaml, yq

Using [the yq tool](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/), is there any way to make it assign/update a value to be empty (not empty string or `null`, just empty)?

For example, the current behavior is this:

```
yq eval --null-input '.a = "cat"'
a: cat

yq eval --null-input '.a = ""'      
a: ""
```

Whereas I want the output to be:

```
a:
```

The reason is I want to maintain compatibility with the convention of a file I am working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the tag to `!!null`, yq will output the scalar without quotes:

```
yq eval --null-input '.a="" | .a tag="!!null"'
```